# how can I install gulp for windows 7?

Tags: node.js, windows-7, npm, gulp

Trying to install gulp with npm :

```
npm install gulp
```

Getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/-/minimist-1.1.1.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/-/minimist-1.1.1.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/minimist/-/minimist-1.1.1.tgz
npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "gulp"
npm ERR! cwd C:\gulpapp
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Then I tried this:

```
npm config set proxy=null
```

Did not solve it either. How get around this?

Comment: I assume you're seeing issues with this for all modules, is that correct?

Comment: _Are_ you behind a proxy?

Comment: I am also facing exactly same issue. Did you find the solution?